# Java Socket Permission error

Tags: java, sockets, permission-denied, access-denied

Please help me resolve the following Java error msg when attempting to make a remote connection to a device in my office. I can connect from another CPU to the device, but not from my laptop.  So, I know its a file in my laptop config somewhere.  I have updated Java several times.  Can someone tell me which file it is and exactly how to resolve this?

Also, the URL socket is supposed to be 5800...but the error msg shows socket 5900 for some reason!

Error: access denied (“java.netSocketPermission””172.30.150.88:5900””connect,resolve”)

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone tell me which file it is and exactly how to resolve this?

It is not possible.  The location of that configuration file depends entirely on the Java application you are running.

If you were running Linux, I would say "use `find` and `grep` to search for the file".

---

The other thing to note is that you appear to have a Java security exception.  That suggests that on your laptop the code is being run in a security sandbox.  If that is the case, there is a distinct possibility that it is blocking *all* connects ... and that fixing the port number won't solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying Stephen.  I disabled the Sandbox feature in Java settings and still have the issue.  The app is a Windows based system, not Linux.  Is there a Java policy file blocking access do you think?

Comment: If you are not running the Java code in a sandbox, then Java won't be what is responsible for blocking access.  Of course, it could be something else; e.g. Window security, firewall, etc.